# Time-based manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R, and I believe my problem may require more than just R knowledge. My data set is made up of weekly measurements taken at 10-minute intervals. The measurement begins at 4 a.m. and ends at 3.50 a.m. over the course of 24 hours (e.g. 7days x 144 measurements [24hours x 60minutes / 10 every10minutes]).

```
Variables definition:

day1_1=the first measurement of day 1
day1_2=the second measurement of day 1
```

....

```
day2_1 = the first measurement of day 2
day2_2 = the second measurement of day 2
```

......

```
id=identification number
```

a.)First, I would like to identify measurements that were taken at the same time over the course `of a week per id`.

For example how to identify if there are similar values for the first measurement during the week; eg. `day1_1 measurement =day2_1 measurement = ...=day7_1 measurement?`

[image]

```
Sample data in long:

structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("day1_1", 
"day1_2", "day1_3", "day2_1", "day2_2", "day2_3", "day3_1", "day3_2", 
"day3_3", "day4_1", "day4_2", "day4_3", "day5_1", "day5_2", "day5_3", 
"day6_1", "day6_2", "day6_3", "day7_1", "day7_2", "day7_3"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(110, 111, 320, 110, 110, 100, 320, 110, 111, 456, 
    111, 111, 110, 220, 100, 456, 3310, 100, 3310, 100, 3310, 
    456, 3310, 3310, 110, 110, 220, 110, 3310, 220, 100, 3310, 
    3310, 100, 3310, 3310, 110, 320, 220, 110, 3310, 220, 100, 
    3310, 3310, 100, 3310, 456, 110, 110, 220, 110, 3310, 456, 
    100, 3310, 3310, 320, 220, 3310, 110, 100, 110, 456, 3310, 
    456, 100, 3310, 100, 3310, 220, 456, 110, 220, 100, 320, 
    3310, 100, 320, 100, 3310, 220, 456, 320)), row.names = c(NA, 
-84L), class = "data.frame")
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), day1_1 = c(110, 111, 320, 
110), day1_2 = c(110, 100, 320, 110), day1_3 = c(111, 456, 111, 
111), day2_1 = c(110, 220, 100, 456), day2_2 = c(3310, 100, 3310, 
100), day2_3 = c(3310, 456, 3310, 3310), day3_1 = c(110, 110, 
220, 110), day3_2 = c(3310, 220, 100, 3310), day3_3 = c(3310, 
100, 3310, 3310), day4_1 = c(110, 320, 220, 110), day4_2 = c(3310, 
220, 100, 3310), day4_3 = c(3310, 100, 3310, 456), day5_1 = c(110, 
110, 220, 110), day5_2 = c(3310, 456, 100, 3310), day5_3 = c(3310, 
320, 220, 3310), day6_1 = c(110, 100, 110, 456), day6_2 = c(3310, 
456, 100, 3310), day6_3 = c(100, 3310, 220, 456), day7_1 = c(110, 
220, 100, 320), day7_2 = c(3310, 100, 320, 100), day7_3 = c(3310, 
220, 456, 320)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), day1_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day1_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day1_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day2_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day2_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day2_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day3_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day3_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day3_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day4_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day4_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day4_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day5_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day5_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day5_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day6_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day6_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day6_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day7_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day7_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day7_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Convert your data to long format (using `pivot_longer`) and the vast majority of your problems will disappear or become much simpler.

Comment: @Limey I converted my data in long format but how to select specific days and how to identify if the measurement on specific days is equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this might help you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), day1_1 = c(
  110, 111, 320,
  110
), day1_2 = c(110, 100, 320, 110), day1_3 = c(
  111, 456, 111,
  111
), day2_1 = c(110, 220, 100, 456), day2_2 = c(
  3310, 100, 3310,
  100
), day2_3 = c(3310, 456, 3310, 3310), day3_1 = c(
  110, 110,
  220, 110
), day3_2 = c(3310, 220, 100, 3310), day3_3 = c(
  3310,
  100, 3310, 3310
), day4_1 = c(110, 320, 220, 110), day4_2 = c(
  3310,
  220, 100, 3310
), day4_3 = c(3310, 100, 3310, 456), day5_1 = c(
  110,
  110, 220, 110
), day5_2 = c(3310, 456, 100, 3310), day5_3 = c(
  3310,
  320, 220, 3310
), day6_1 = c(110, 100, 110, 456), day6_2 = c(
  3310,
  456, 100, 3310
), day6_3 = c(100, 3310, 220, 456), day7_1 = c(
  110,
  220, 100, 320
), day7_2 = c(3310, 100, 320, 100), day7_3 = c(
  3310,
  220, 456, 320
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
  id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), day1_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day1_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day1_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day2_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day2_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day2_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day3_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day3_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day3_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day4_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day4_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day4_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day5_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day5_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day5_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day6_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day6_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day6_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day7_1 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day7_2 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), day7_3 = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  ))
), default = structure(list(), class = c(
  "collector_guess",
  "collector"
)), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

data_2 <-
  data %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("day", "timepoint"), sep = "_") %>%
  arrange(timepoint)
data_2
#> # A tibble: 84 x 4
#>       id day   timepoint value
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1     1 day1  1           110
#>  2     1 day2  1           110
#>  3     1 day3  1           110
#>  4     1 day4  1           110
#>  5     1 day5  1           110
#>  6     1 day6  1           110
#>  7     1 day7  1           110
#>  8     2 day1  1           111
#>  9     2 day2  1           220
#> 10     2 day3  1           110
#> # … with 74 more rows

# select specific days
data_2 %>%
  filter(day == "day2")
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>       id day   timepoint value
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1     1 day2  1           110
#>  2     2 day2  1           220
#>  3     3 day2  1           100
#>  4     4 day2  1           456
#>  5     1 day2  2          3310
#>  6     2 day2  2           100
#>  7     3 day2  2          3310
#>  8     4 day2  2           100
#>  9     1 day2  3          3310
#> 10     2 day2  3           456
#> 11     3 day2  3          3310
#> 12     4 day2  3          3310

# measurements for an id on a day with the same value
data_2 %>%
  group_by(id, day, value) %>%
  count() %>%
  filter(n > 1)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, day, value [15]
#>       id day   value     n
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1 day1    110     2
#>  2     1 day2   3310     2
#>  3     1 day3   3310     2
#>  4     1 day4   3310     2
#>  5     1 day5   3310     2
#>  6     1 day7   3310     2
#>  7     2 day7    220     2
#>  8     3 day1    320     2
#>  9     3 day2   3310     2
#> 10     3 day5    220     2
#> 11     4 day1    110     2
#> 12     4 day3   3310     2
#> 13     4 day5   3310     2
#> 14     4 day6    456     2
#> 15     4 day7    320     2

# Overview plot
qplot(x = timepoint, y = value, color = day, data = data_2, geom = "point", size = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code with data_2 %>%
  group_by(id, timepoint, value) %>%
  count() %>%
  filter(n == 7)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer data.table to manipulate my data, but you can do with dplyr as well of course. Either way, starting with R and data, it is advisable to study one of them at least. I suggest to prepare your data like this, so you have a seperate column for your day and for timeslot.

```
dt <- copy(df)

library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt <- melt(dt, id = c("id"))
cols <-  c("day", "timeslot")
dt[, (cols) := tstrsplit(str_remove_all(variable, "[[:alpha:]]"), "_", fixed = T)]
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = cols]

head(dt, 15)
#     id variable value day timeslot
#  1:  1   day1_1   110   1        1
#  2:  2   day1_1   111   1        1
#  3:  3   day1_1   320   1        1
#  4:  4   day1_1   110   1        1
#  5:  1   day1_2   110   1        2
#  6:  2   day1_2   100   1        2
#  7:  3   day1_2   320   1        2
#  8:  4   day1_2   110   1        2
#  9:  1   day1_3   111   1        3
# 10:  2   day1_3   456   1        3
# 11:  3   day1_3   111   1        3
# 12:  4   day1_3   111   1        3
# 13:  1   day2_1   110   2        1
# 14:  2   day2_1   220   2        1
# 15:  3   day2_1   100   2        1

str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    84 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ id      : num  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#  $ variable: Factor w/ 21 levels "day1_1","day1_2",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
#  $ value   : num  110 111 320 110 110 100 320 110 111 456 ...
#  $ day     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ timeslot: num  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
```

From here you can play around with this data and answer your questions.